# Node.js Cognito sends # before token in URL

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, amazon-cognito

I have a cognito setup (with only `Implicit Grant` enabled) and have `http://localhost:8000/login` as callback login URL specified.

I have a backend side(`Node.js`) which expects GET request on /login endpoint and I plan to parse/verify token there.

When login is done it redirects me to `http://localhost:8000/login#id_token=...`

The problem is that as I know the part of the URL starting with the `#` symbol is never sent to the server. So how can I receive the token from `Node.js` side?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn’t be using implicit flow. It’s an outdated and insecure feature of OAuth. The token is passed in the hash specifically because it is meant for client side applications. Since you have a nodejs backend as your client you should be going through a authorization code (with PKCE) grant.

Comment: I will attempt to make a correction here. What is pending formal deprecation in the OAuth 2.1 and OAuth Security Topics BCP drafts are the response types that result in an Access Token being issued directly by the authorization_endpoint. That includes the following response types - `token`, `id_token token`, `code token`, `code id_token token`.

A pure OIDC response type of `response_type=id_token` is not deprecated and is perfectly safe to use, especially for a login scenario.

Answer (score 0):

What is the response type used? Is it `response_type=id_token`? In that case, in order to have it sent to a backend for a simple OIDC Login flow you have two options

1. add `response_mode=form_post`, which will result in the IdP triggering a self submitting POST form to your `redirect_uri`
2. add a "re-post" handler to your GET `redirect_uri` that will read the fragment portion and POST it to your backend.

Each of the two has its benefits as well as drawbacks.